# Why doesn't $(window).animate scrollTop work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If the following code works (which certainly does)

```
$( 'html, body' ).animate(
    {
        "scrollTop": "500"
    }, 
    500
);
```

then why doesn't the following code work?

```
$( window ).animate(
    {
        "scrollTop": "500"
    }, 
    500
);
```

If the following code works

```
$( window ).scroll( myScrollFunctionHandler );
```

then why doesn't the following code work?

```
$( 'html, body' ).scroll( myScrollFunctionHandler );
```

Can somebody please make a comprehensive explanation as to why this has to be this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window` does not have a scrollTop property, which is why your first example doesn't work. `document.body` does.

As to your second example, `$(window).scroll` is the event handler installer for [window.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onscroll). There is no "body onscroll" event, so obviously an event handler installed on the body (or html) element won't be invoked, as events do not bubble down the DOM, but only up.

Comment: what do you mean it's not standard? Nope, it accepts a callback function that will be used when the selected object is scrolled.

Comment: I was wrong about the $.scroll - that's a scroll handler, not a scroll function (like scrollTo, which I was confusing it for). The reason for the discrepancy is that the onscroll event fires on the window object, not the body element.

Answer (score 2):

This should be due to the internal working of `$(window).animate()`. Experiment results suggested that inside this jQuery animate() code, `$(window).scrollTop()` would ALWAYS return zero and `$(window).scrollTop(value)` could NOT set the value properly.

However, these work before the `animate()` and in its step callback function. Thus, the code like below would work properly.

```
function scrollNow(final_val){
    var initial_val = $(window).scrollTop(),
        diff = final_val - initial_val
    ;
    $(window).animate(
        {
            scrollTop: diff,
        },
        {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function(now, fx){
               $(window).scrollTop(initial_val + now);
            }
        }
    );
}
```